# How to enable fingureprint login in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: security, fingerprint-reader, unlock

I have a fingerprint sensor on my laptop. Previously I used it on my windows. is there any way to enable fingureprint log in in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->users->Authentication & login.
Under Authentication & Login, click on Fingerprint Login.
Click Scan new fingerprint button. setup finger that's all.
Repeat the steps to add additional fingers.